# Ckeditor event handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have a table, I want each cell can be editable.
I each cell can be editable when user click on a cell.

My code can done the job well, I want the updated data can be updated to server database when the editing complete, so I capture the blur event to do so, the problem is when I select text color in toolbar, the blur event is triggered also, so, would you tell me to fix the issue? Or is there any other method to get the job done.

Here is my code:

```
            <html>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
                <script language="javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
                <script language="javascript" src="ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
                <script language="javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("[id^='editor']").ckeditor().on("blur",function(){alert($(this).ckeditor().editor.getData());return false;});                                                             </script>   
            </head>
            <body>
                <table border=1>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="editor1" contenteditable="true">
                                <h1>Inline Editing in Action!</h1>
                                <p>The "div" element that contains this text is now editable.</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="editor2" contenteditable="true">
                                <h1>Inline Editing in Action!</h1>
                                <p>The "div" element that contains this text is now editable.
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>           
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Here is my config.js

```
        CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
            // Define changes to default configuration here.
            // For complete reference see:
            // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

            // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for a single toolbar row.
            config.toolbarGroups = [
                { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
                { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
                { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
                { name: 'forms' },
                { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
                { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
                { name: 'links' },
                { name: 'insert' },
                { name: 'styles' },
                { name: 'colors' },
                { name: 'tools' },
                { name: 'others' },
                { name: 'about' }
            ];

            // The default plugins included in the basic setup define some buttons that
            // are not needed in a basic editor. They are removed here.
            config.removeButtons = 'Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript,Link,Unlink,Styles,About,HorizontalRule,Blockquote,Italic,SpellChecker,SpecialChar,Format';

            // Dialog windows are also simplified.
            config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';

            config.extraPlugins = 'onchange';
        };
```

thank you very much

Comment: Blur should not be fired when you open text color panel and choose any color in it. I checked it and it WFM – blur isn't fired until I really blur the editor. So if you can create a sample showing the error it's worth reporting it on http://dev.ckeditor.com.